# Seeking Assistance with Implementing a Compact Drawer UI in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mobile

I apologize if my question lacks clarity or sufficient details last time. I'm attempting to replicate a specific user interface as shown in the attached pictures, where a small drawer emerges from the bottom. We've successfully implemented this in UIKit, but are encountering challenges in SwiftUI. Our current approach involves using .sheet with medium and large detents, but we haven't found a way to create a smaller detent like the one in our design.

We also explored using UIViewControllerRepresentable to integrate the UIKit view into SwiftUI, but this approach has not been successful. Specifically, we're facing an issue with a view named "Presentation Hosting Controller" that consistently displays a white screen. The only workaround we've found is to use fullScreenCover, which doesn't align with our design goals.

**Update**

I add SwiftUI code of how were converting that UIKit view to a SwiftUI View and what the UIKit view code. Also I added pictures of whats going one.

Could someone provide guidance on the best way to achieve this small drawer effect in SwiftUI? Your expertise and suggestions would be greatly appreciated. If you need more details please let me know.

**Sheet**

When I convert it and show the view in a sheet this what it look like and it View Hierarch

[How it looks with sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dg0Qy.png)

[View Hierarch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocQUt.png)

**fullScreenCover**

This how it looks with fullScreenCover, the problem with this is that black screen that behind which supppose to A make the back UI untouchable and B look alittle litter. What going on is that its sliding up into the view with the small sheet and as soon you touch anymore on the view it will dismis.

[Sorry for the markups but this what is look like with fullScreenCover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxS3C.png)

[This the Hierarch of the fullScreenCover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX9tR.png)

**UIkit View - How suppose to look**

[This the Drawer I'm talking about that has been done in UIKit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJUdW.png)

[You see in the UIkit when where calling Action sheet its not being black or sandwich with so many view in between](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnDdO.png)

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct EngagementPaymentView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: EngagementViewModel
    var closeWithoutSavingAction: () -> Void
    @SwiftUI.State var isActionSheetSelected: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    ScrollView {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 32) {
                            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 16) {
                                
                                PaymentMethodsView(viewModel: viewModel)
                            }
                            .padding(0)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
                        }
                        .padding(16)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
                        .background(.white)
                    }
                    .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom, spacing: 0) {
                        Spacer()
                            .frame(height: 150)
                    }
                    .background(Color(Color.graySmoke.color))
                    
                    HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 16) {
                        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 8) {
                            Button {
                                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                            } label: {
                                EngagementButton(buttonTitle: "Back", textColor: Color.blackPearl.color, buttonColor: Color.white.color, showOverlay: true, isLoading: .constant(false))
                            }
                            NavigationLink {
                                    EngagementEsignView(viewModel: viewModel, closeWithoutSavingAction: closeWithoutSavingAction)
                            } label: {
                                EngagementButton(buttonTitle: "Next", textColor: Color.white.color, buttonColor: Color.primary.color, isDisabled: true, showOverlay: false, isLoading: .constant(false))
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(16)
                        .frame(width: 360, alignment: .leading)
                        .background(Color(Color.white.color))
                    }
                }
            }.sheet(isPresented: $isActionSheetSelected) {
                    ActionSheetSwiftUIView(actions: [ActionItem(buttonStyle: .button(style: .primary, title: "ABC"))])
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .background(TransparentBackground())
                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2, execute: {
                isActionSheetSelected = true
            })
        }
    }
}


struct ActionSheetSwiftUIView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = ActionSheetController
    var actions = [ActionItem]()
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ActionSheetController {
        let vc = ActionSheetController()
//        vc.view.backgroundColor = .clear
//        vc.sheetView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = .clear
//        vc.sheetView.backgroundColor = .clear
//        vc.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        for action in actions {
            vc.addAction(action)
            vc.addSeparatorView()
        }
        return vc
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ActionSheetController, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
struct TransparentBackground: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            view.superview?.superview?.backgroundColor = .clear
            view.superview?.superview?.superview?.backgroundColor = .clear
        }
        return view
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {}
}
```

```swift
import UIKit

class ActionSheetView: UIView {
    let backgroundView = UIView()

    let cardView = UIView()

    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let stackView = UIStackView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupSubviews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        setupSubviews()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        // Update the height anchor to offset for the bottom safeareainset.
        cardView.snp.updateConstraints { (make) in
            make.height.equalTo(stackView.snp.height).offset(safeAreaInsets.bottom).priority(.low)
        }

        super.layoutSubviews()
    }
}


extension ActionSheetView: View {
    func configureSubviews() {
        accessibilityIdentifier = "ActionSheetView"

        backgroundView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
        backgroundView.accessibilityIdentifier = "ActionSheetBackground"
        addSubview(backgroundView)

        cardView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cardView.backgroundColor = Color.grayAsh.color
        addSubview(cardView)

        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cardView.addSubview(scrollView)

        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.alignment = .fill
        stackView.distribution = .fill
        stackView.spacing = 0
        stackView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: UIConstants.edgeInset, left: 0, bottom: UIConstants.edgeInset, right: 0)
        stackView.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
    }

    func configureConstraints() {
        backgroundView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }

        cardView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.leading.equalToSuperview()
            make.trailing.equalToSuperview()
            make.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(0)
            make.height.equalTo(stackView.snp.height).offset(safeAreaInsets.bottom).priority(.low)
            // Use the superview height with a multiplier here to avoid a crash when the card view nearly fills the height allotted, just before becoming a scrollable view
            make.height.lessThanOrEqualToSuperview().multipliedBy(0.8).priority(.high)
        }

        scrollView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.equalToSuperview()
            make.leading.equalToSuperview()
            make.trailing.equalToSuperview()
            make.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        }

        stackView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
            make.width.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom `Sheet` detents using the `.presentationDetents` modifier. The detents can be fixed heights or fractions of the screen size. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/presentationdetent

```
struct SheetDetentsView: View {
    @State private var showSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Show Sheet", action: { showSheet = true })
            .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
                VStack {
                    Text("First detent is fixed height of 200...")
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.up")
                    Text("Slide up for detent of 75% of screen...")
                }
                .padding()
                .presentationDetents([.height(200), .fraction(0.75)])
            }
    }
}
```